# Why is KeyCode.ESCAPE being consumed by ComboBoxes and what is the work around?

Tags: java, javafx-2

In my standalone JavaFX 2 application hitting the Escape key should trigger an event that shuts the application down. But then it started not working sporadically.  With further testing I realized that when any of several ComboBox components on the main display have focus, hitting Escape did nothing. But if you then click a TableView, TextBox, Button, etc. to give them the focus, it would work fine. It also stops again if focus returns to the ComboBox. Changing the triggering event to other KeyCodes seemed to fix the issue no matter which item has focus.

So focused ComboBoxes appear to be consuming KeyCode.ESCAPE events. But why? And is there a way to fix this without keeping them from obtaining focus or changing the event handler to some other key?

Comment: Are you using an [EventFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/filters.htm) or [EventHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/handlers.htm) to listen for the `KeyCode.ESCAPE` event?

Comment: EventHandler. The code looks like this:
`scene.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>()
        {
            public void handle(KeyEvent kEvnt)
            {
                if (kEvnt.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE)
                {
                    ShutdownApp(true);
                }
            }
        });`

Answer (score 1):

I think its the contained ListView popup that consumes the *ESCAPE* keycode because when the ListView popup is opened, hitting the escape key will close it. If you use the EventFilter mentioned by OttPrime it should work as you expect...

```
    scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent ke)
        {
            if (ke.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE)
            {
                shutDownApp(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You should probably also call `ke.consume()` to avoid other controls to capture the event and possibly start doing something about it.